# How can I get container id from cgroup v1 with ebpf code?

Tags: linux-kernel, containers, ebpf, bpf, cgroups

How can I get container id from cgroup v1 with ebpf code? I can access task_struct->cgroups, but it(task_struct->cgroups) pointer content all zero.so I try task_struct->sched_task_group ,but always can not get container id。I try task_struct->group_leader and (task_struct->cgroups->dfl_cgrp) ,but result all failed.

i expect get container_id by task_struct in ebpf program

Comment: I'm unsure what the container ID is. Do you mean the cgroup ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the cgroup ID using [the `bpf_get_current_cgroup_id` helper](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html):

```
u64 bpf_get_current_cgroup_id(void)
```